# Short film from 70s or early 80s; Child hides and light pours through a keyhole

Tags: story-identification, short-film

In public school in the early to mid 80s I saw a short film that (as best I can recall) ends with a kid hiding in the dark behind a door as extremely bright light from the other side of the door streams through its keyhole. Perhaps the doorknob begins melting--I'm not certain whether this is an embellishment on my part. I think the light source may be aliens.

I don't remember any dialog, but assume it was in English if there was any. I think the character was a young boy, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Was the film in English or some other language? Do you recall the gender or general description of the kid?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Sci-Fi.SE... Could you please change the title to be a little bit more descriptive and make it more 'searchable'? Thanks!

Comment: Which country did you view this?

Answer (score 7):

It's not a short film, but [the abduction scene from *Close Encounters of the Third Kind*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuH_qx192js) is similar to what you've described.

Edit: [Much longer clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8x-eHPmvO4).

Comment: Wow--I had forgotten about that scene! The beginning of the clip certainly fits the bill, but I believe the light through the keyhole was the end of the film I saw, leaving you to wonder what happens.

Answer (score 5):

You are positively describing the short film called "Zero Hour" which was based on Ray Bradbury's short story of the same name.  I used to watch this film repeatedly at the community college where my mother worked and this would have been in the early 80s.  The main character, Mink, was an androgynous looking girl.  At the end of the film her parents are hiding in the attic when aliens invade through the keyhole.  A decade after this film, Ray Bradbury Theater remade it with different actors but it was not as good as the original.

Answer (score 2):

The ending of The Ray Bradbury Theather ["Zero Hour"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spIVwo6DAIE) episode is similar, but the adults are the ones hiding. Also, the episode is from 1992, not the early 80's.

Answer (score 1):

I showed that short educational film, “Zero Hour” many times as a middle school English teacher 1970s - 2008. It was black and white and based uponRay Bradbury’s story of the same title. It was almost the same as the later Ray Bradbury Theater version. In BOTH films, the parents hide in the attic.

Comment: Whilst this may or may not be correct it would be better if you could [edit] in how this matches the OPs description.